# How to refresh the datasource in XPages, when you change background document?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

If I get the NotesDocument object from the datasource, change some fields and then save the datasource, without saving the NotesDocument directly, the changes are not saved.

For example:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
doc.replaceItemValue("TestField", "Test");
```

I save the datasource with the simple action and the field "TestField" in the document is empty.

How can I update datasource with the changes in the background document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steve's correct, if you want to update the back-end document and reflect that on the DominoDocument wrapper datasource, you need to save.

But based on your answer, why are you trying to update the back-end document? It would seem to make more sense to update the DominoDocument instead with `document1.replaceItemValue("TestField", "test")`.

In queryNewDocument there no back-end document exists. During `document1.save()`, the code will effectively call `database.createDocument()`, then write all fields from `document1` onto that newly-created Document object. If a Document object was created earlier, you would hit the problem you're raising in your comment on Steve's answer - needing to delete the Document object if the save is cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

In SSJS, you have to explicitly save your backend document.  To do this simply add a line to save the document changes. I am not sure why the simple action didn't work for you, but add this line and your "Test Field" will be updated.

```
doc.save();
```

Comment: But I don't want to save the document at this time. I have this code in the queryNewDocument event. It is possible, that the doc will be cancelled.

Comment: Guess I am not understanding...are you saying that you want the front end UI to change based on changes made to the backed document?  Your words seem to say this, but your code says something else. If this is the case, please try performing and event with a full refresh of your XPage. This should reload the data including any changes made to the backend document.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add Authors field to the document and I do it in the queryNewDocument event.

```
document1.replaceItemValue("Authors", authors);
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
    if (doc != null) {
        var Authors:NotesItem = doc.getFirstItem("Authors");
        Authors.setAuthors(true);
    }
```

But If I don't save the with doc.save() and only do document1.save() at the end, then the field 'Authors' stays a usual text field.
And I don't want to save the doc before user clicks save button.

Is there any better way to add Authors field to a new document?

Comment: I would consider: 1) Adding the author field when the users saves the button or 2) if that isn't feasible then in the save button you could make a new Authors field, assign the value that you set earlier and then setAuthors(true) and see if the author field sticks.

Comment: I had strange effects, when there is no Authors field in the document and the current user has author level, he cannot  go to edit mode. 
Anyway, I have solved it by adding  `Authors.setAuthors(true);` before save the document.